# recursive big-o for modified cases from merge sort (T(n/2) + cn)

Tags: big-o

what would be the big-o for
   T(n)= T(n/2) + cn

I know the mergesort case T(n) = 2T(n/2)+cn i.e. linearithmic

and i was able to solve T(n) = 2T(n/2)+c to get linear but am confused in the first one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one should be pretty simple:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + cn = T(n/4) + cn/2 + cn = T(n/8) + cn/4 + cn/2 + cn
     = T(1) + c(n/2^m + ... + n/4 + n/2 + n)
     <= T(1) + c(n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ...) = 2cn + T(1)
```

Where `m = log(n)`.

Hence in terms of big-o notation `T(n) ~ O(n)`.

BTW, not hard to prove this is actually theta of n,

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + cn = T(n/4) + cn/2 + cn = T(n/8) + cn/4 + cn/2 + cn
     = T(1) + c(n/2^m + ... + n/4 + n/2 + n)
     >= T(1) + c(n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ...) = cn + T(1)
```

and therefore `T(n)` is actually theta of n, since both big-o and big-omega of n.